# How to mock object instantiated in google cloud function global scope

Tags: python

I have been reading some of Google's best practices for Cloud Functions. They mention creating HTTP sessions and connections to Google Cloud APIs in the global scope so that connections can be reused. Here's the relevant link:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/networking#maintaining_persistent_connections

Here's are the two examples from that page:

[image]

[image]

What do you do if you now need to mock one of these classes in a test? I am trying to do it with the patch decorator, but I am finding that the original class is still being used, presumably because the code is being executed when the main module is read, which is too late for the patch decorator:

```py
# main.py

import os
import bigcommerce

# Create this global api object so that the http connection can be reused
api = bigcommerce.api.BigcommerceApi(client_id=os.getenv('CLIENT_ID'), store_hash=os.getenv('STORE_HASH'), access_token=os.getenv('AUTH_TOKEN'))

def my_cloud_function():
    # Fetch product id 1 from the api
    product = api.Products.get(1)
    print(product)
```

```py
# test_my_cloud_function.py

import main
from unittest import mock

@patch('main.bigcommerce.api.BigcommerceApi')
def test_product_is_fetched(mock_api):
    mock_api.return_value.Products.get.return_value = {'id': 1, 'name': 'foo'}
    main.my_cloud_function()
```

When I run this test, I can an error from the actual BigCommerce API, because the real class is being used. However, if I move the creation of the api object out of the global scope and put it inside `my_cloud_function`, then when the test runs I see the expected `{'id': 1, 'name': 'foo'}` printed out.

I am confused how you are supposed to use the global object as Google suggests, while still being able to test properly. Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: the `api` object is created when your `main` module is first imported. Make sure you do that import __after__ the patching is done i.e. inside the test. Or refactor your `main` module to not create `api` during module loading

Comment: @rdas I tried this. I moved `import main` into the test function, but the real class is still being used instead of the mock. Is that not expected?